# LISTAGG function not combining row values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data (additional columns omitted) from SQL query.

```
INVOICE_ID        INVOICE_AMT   INV_LINE_NUMBER    HOLD_CODE
300000155983977   51403         1                  AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         2                  AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         3                  AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         1                  MAX AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         2                  MAX AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         3                  MAX AMY ORD
```

As you can see there are two different `HOLD_CODE` values for each of the 3 line numbers. What I want to do is combine the rows by using the **LISTAGG** function to concatenate the `HOLD_CODE` values based on the `INVOICE_ID` (and I believe `INV_LINE_NUMBER` as well)

My **Desired Results** would be the following:

```
INVOICE_ID        INVOICE_AMT   INV_LINE_NUMBER    HOLD_CODE
300000155983977   51403         1                  AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         2                  AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         3                  AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
```

I have modified the SQL to use the LISTAGG function on the `HOLD_CODE` column, however it is not outputting as expected. Below is the **LISTAGG** function I added:

```
SELECT
 ai.invoice_id,
 nvl(ai.amount,0) invoice_amt,
 ai.line_number Inv_line_number,
    (SELECT LISTAGG( decode(ahc1.postable_flag,'N',ah1.hold_lookup_code, '') , ',') WITHIN 
      GROUP (ORDER BY decode(ahc1.postable_flag,'N',ah1.hold_lookup_code, '') )
       FROM ap_hold_codes ahc1, ap_holds_all ah1
      WHERE ah1.hold_lookup_code = ahc1.hold_lookup_code
        AND ahc1.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE = ahc.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE
        AND ah1.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE = ah.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE 
        AND ah1.invoice_id = ah.invoice_id
        AND    ah1.invoice_id = ai.invoice_id
      GROUP BY  ah.invoice_id   , ai.invoice_num   ) hold_code
                                        
     --(Additional columns omitted for simplification)
FROM   (  select distinct
                        apexp.invoice_id
                      -- ,invoice_num
                                                                          ,( CASE 
          (apexp.source_type)
            WHEN 'INCMPLT_INV' THEN
              CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num, 0,8)
              WHEN 'Invalid-' THEN
               CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num,9,LENGTH(apexp.invoice_id))
              WHEN TO_CHAR(apexp.invoice_id) THEN
                  (SELECT displayed_field
                  FROM ap_lookup_codes
                  WHERE lookup_code = 'INVALID'
                  AND lookup_type   ='NLS TRANSLATION'
                  )
                ELSE
                  apexp.invoice_num
                END
              ELSE
                CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num, 0,10)
                WHEN 'Duplicate-' THEN
                  CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num,11,LENGTH(apexp.invoice_id))
                  WHEN TO_CHAR(apexp.invoice_id) THEN
                    (SELECT alc.displayed_field
                      ||':'
                      ||air.token_value2
                    FROM ap_lookup_codes alc,
                      ap_interface_rejections air
                    WHERE alc.lookup_code     ='DUPLICATE'
                    AND alc.lookup_type       ='NLS TRANSLATION'
                    AND air.reject_lookup_code='DUPLICATE INVOICE NUMBER'
                    AND air.invoice_id        =apexp.invoice_id
                    )
                  ELSE
                    apexp.invoice_num
                  END
                ELSE
                  apexp.invoice_num
                END
              END
            ELSE
              apexp.invoice_num
            END) AS invoice_num
                       ,apexp.invoice_date
                       ,apexp.invoice_currency_code
                       ,NVL(aida.amount,AILA.AMOUNT) amount
                       ,apexp.doc_sequence_value
                       ,apexp.voucher_num
                       ,apexp.org_id
                       ,apexp.party_id                -- fusion v1 UATR
                       ,aila.line_number line_number
                       ,aida.distribution_line_number distribution_line_number
                       ,aida.dist_code_combination_id dist_code_combination_id                     
                    from ap_period_close_excps_gt apexp 
                    ,AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL aila
                    ,ap_invoice_distributions_all aida
                    where apexp.source_type in ( 'LINES_WITHOUT_DISTS'
                                               , 'UNACCT_DISTS'
                                               ,'UNACCT_PREPAY_HIST'                                               
                                               ,'INCMPLT_INV'  )
                                               
                         and apexp.invoice_id=aila.invoice_id   
                         and aila.invoice_id=aida.invoice_id(+)
                         and aida.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER(+)=aila.LINE_NUMBER
                         and aila.line_type_lookup_code  in ('ITEM','FREIGHT')                       
                        and   (NVL(:G_SWEEP_NOW,'N') = 'N' OR (:G_SWEEP_NOW = 'Y' AND 
               apexp.process_status_flag = 'Y'))
                        ORDER BY aida.distribution_line_number
                                                                     )  ai
     ,ap_holds_all ah
     ,ap_hold_codes ahc
   WHERE ai.invoice_id = ah.invoice_id
     AND   ah.hold_lookup_code = ahc.hold_lookup_code    
     AND  (ah.release_lookup_code is null and
                      ahc.postable_flag = 'N'  and
                      ah.hold_lookup_code is not null and
                      alc.lookup_type = 'HOLD CODE' and
                      alc.lookup_code = ah.hold_lookup_code)
```

The results are concatenating each HOLD_CODE for each line as you can see below, which is still resulting in 6 rows being output, instead of 3. The is not what I need it to be:

```
    INVOICE_ID        INVOICE_AMT   INV_LINE_NUMBER    HOLD_CODE
    300000155983977   51403         1                  AMT ORD, AMT ORD, AMT ORD
    300000155983977   51403         2                  AMT ORD, AMT ORD, AMT ORD
    300000155983977   51403         3                  AMT ORD, AMT ORD, AMT ORD
    300000155983977   51403         1                  MAX AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
    300000155983977   51403         2                  MAX AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
    300000155983977   51403         3                  MAX AMY ORD, MAX AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
```

Again my **desired results** would be the following:

```
INVOICE_ID        INVOICE_AMT   INV_LINE_NUMBER    HOLD_CODE
300000155983977   51403         1                  AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         2                  AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
300000155983977   51403         3                  AMT ORD, MAX AMT ORD
```

Answer (score 2):

You should apply `LISTAGG` outside of your query, not inside. It should work on your current output, not on a subquery of it.

```
SELECT
 ai.invoice_id,
 nvl(ai.amount,0) invoice_amt,
 ai.line_number Inv_line_number,
    LISTAGG(SELECT decode(ahc1.postable_flag,'N',ah1.hold_lookup_code, '') AS decoded_code
       FROM ap_hold_codes ahc1, ap_holds_all ah1
      WHERE ah1.hold_lookup_code = ahc1.hold_lookup_code
        AND ahc1.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE = ahc.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE
        AND ah1.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE = ah.HOLD_LOOKUP_CODE 
        AND ah1.invoice_id = ah.invoice_id
        AND    ah1.invoice_id = ai.invoice_id
      GROUP BY  ah.invoice_id   , ai.invoice_num   ), ',') WITHIN 
      GROUP (ORDER BY decoded_code) hold_code
                                        
     --(Additional columns omitted for simplification)
FROM   (  select distinct
                        apexp.invoice_id
                      -- ,invoice_num
                                                                          ,( CASE 
          (apexp.source_type)
            WHEN 'INCMPLT_INV' THEN
              CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num, 0,8)
              WHEN 'Invalid-' THEN
               CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num,9,LENGTH(apexp.invoice_id))
              WHEN TO_CHAR(apexp.invoice_id) THEN
                  (SELECT displayed_field
                  FROM ap_lookup_codes
                  WHERE lookup_code = 'INVALID'
                  AND lookup_type   ='NLS TRANSLATION'
                  )
                ELSE
                  apexp.invoice_num
                END
              ELSE
                CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num, 0,10)
                WHEN 'Duplicate-' THEN
                  CASE SUBSTR(apexp.invoice_num,11,LENGTH(apexp.invoice_id))
                  WHEN TO_CHAR(apexp.invoice_id) THEN
                    (SELECT alc.displayed_field
                      ||':'
                      ||air.token_value2
                    FROM ap_lookup_codes alc,
                      ap_interface_rejections air
                    WHERE alc.lookup_code     ='DUPLICATE'
                    AND alc.lookup_type       ='NLS TRANSLATION'
                    AND air.reject_lookup_code='DUPLICATE INVOICE NUMBER'
                    AND air.invoice_id        =apexp.invoice_id
                    )
                  ELSE
                    apexp.invoice_num
                  END
                ELSE
                  apexp.invoice_num
                END
              END
            ELSE
              apexp.invoice_num
            END) AS invoice_num
                       ,apexp.invoice_date
                       ,apexp.invoice_currency_code
                       ,NVL(aida.amount,AILA.AMOUNT) amount
                       ,apexp.doc_sequence_value
                       ,apexp.voucher_num
                       ,apexp.org_id
                       ,apexp.party_id                -- fusion v1 UATR
                       ,aila.line_number line_number
                       ,aida.distribution_line_number distribution_line_number
                       ,aida.dist_code_combination_id dist_code_combination_id                     
                    from ap_period_close_excps_gt apexp 
                    ,AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL aila
                    ,ap_invoice_distributions_all aida
                    where apexp.source_type in ( 'LINES_WITHOUT_DISTS'
                                               , 'UNACCT_DISTS'
                                               ,'UNACCT_PREPAY_HIST'                                               
                                               ,'INCMPLT_INV'  )
                                               
                         and apexp.invoice_id=aila.invoice_id   
                         and aila.invoice_id=aida.invoice_id(+)
                         and aida.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER(+)=aila.LINE_NUMBER
                         and aila.line_type_lookup_code  in ('ITEM','FREIGHT')                       
                        and   (NVL(:G_SWEEP_NOW,'N') = 'N' OR (:G_SWEEP_NOW = 'Y' AND 
               apexp.process_status_flag = 'Y'))
                        ORDER BY aida.distribution_line_number
                                                                     )  ai
     ,ap_holds_all ah
     ,ap_hold_codes ahc
   WHERE ai.invoice_id = ah.invoice_id
     AND   ah.hold_lookup_code = ahc.hold_lookup_code    
     AND  (ah.release_lookup_code is null and
                      ahc.postable_flag = 'N'  and
                      ah.hold_lookup_code is not null and
                      alc.lookup_type = 'HOLD CODE' and
                      alc.lookup_code = ah.hold_lookup_code)
GROUP BY ai.invoice_id,
         nvl(ai.amount,0) invoice_amt,
         ai.line_number Inv_line_number.
         <all non-aggregated fields in the outer query>
```

**Note**: Don't leave `<all non-aggregated fields in the outer query>` in the query: substitute it with your non-aggregated fields.

Comment: I'm getting a MISSING EXPRESSION error with this, is the syntax correct?

Comment: I was hoping to leave the LISTAGG column as a subquery, as I have a lot of additional columns I have that I omitted, is there a way to use the LISTAGG in a Subquery to avoid having to use the Group By on all the other columns?

Comment: For the `MISSING EXPRESSION`, you should look into the note. No, it's not possible, unless you begin simplifying your query a lot. But in that case sample input tables for every table, expected output and a description of what you're attempting to do would be required.

Comment: I'm seeing other threads where LISTAGG function is being used in a Subquery so I'm a little confused why what I have is not working...

Comment: It depends what you aggregate on. In this case, you want to aggregate on the outer query on purpose. Of course you can store everything inside a subquery and do other computations on it. The aggregation has to make sense.

Comment: So the correlated joins I have from the subquery to the main query would not work?

Comment: I'd suggest you 1) to simplify your query 2) to select only and all those fields you really need, otherwise you can't escape from that kind of complexity.

Comment: Ok I understand. My main query uses several sub-query expressions, and I don't believe I can use subqueries inside the GROUP BY clause. Thanks!

Comment: The last GROUP BY in the LISTAGG function does not accept the aliased value 'decoded_code' I believe because it is outside of the subselect scope. Even if I reference the full field (decode(ahc1.postable_flag,'N',ah1.hold_lookup_code, '') then it does not recognize the ahc1.postable_flag and ah1.hold_lookup_code fields. Any ideas what I can do to change this?

Comment: You're aggregating on "*decoded_code*", it's the only field that shouldn't be found inside the `GROUP BY` clause. As a side note, every alias is assigned only after the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get from your query result to the aggregated result is to aggregate your query result:

```
select
  invoice_id, invoice_amt, inv_line_number,
  listagg(hold_code, ', ') within group (order by hold_code) as hold_codes
from ( <your query here> )
group by invoice_id, invoice_amt, inv_line_number
order by invoice_id, invoice_amt, inv_line_number;
```